# Cycling app that uploads to Nike Plus?

Tags: maps, performance-tracking

I am currently using Wahoo to track my cycling (daily commute) mainly because it can upload automatically to Nike+/Fuel so it keeps all my running etc. in the same place.

I've tried googling, but can't find another app that offers this feature, without having to export/import.  Does anyone know of a better alternative to Wahoo that also allows uploads direct to Nike+? [iPhone]

Comment: I would like to close this as off topic because its a question about software, not about bicycles.  However it has a high cycling content too.  So I suggest you ask the same question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and see which SE stack gives the better answer.

Comment: In additional to the position put by @Criggie, I think the question is unclear. Google tells me that there are several Wahoo products. Which one are you using? Do they all work the same? And what's the problem with doing export/import?

Answer (score 1):

[Nike+ is designed for running, the data captured while cycling may not be accurate or useful](http://support-en-us.nikeplus.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42067/p/3169,3179).

I would recommend Strava as a fitness-tracking service which supports multiple sports.

It is possible to [export your old activities from Nike+ to GPX files](https://mattstuehler.com/lab/NikePlus/) which can be imported into Strava (or other apps like Endomondo, Runkeeper...).

Comment: Thanks Emyr, but I'm looking to keep years and years of running data in Nike+ - so can Strava export TO Nike+ (not from it)?

Comment: Nike+ isn't intended for Cycling. All the search results I find for importing into Nike+ involve going via Garmin Connect (which has Nike+ sync).

Comment: I Apologies, I know Nike+ isn't for cycling, but it DOES record all my running going back years and years.  I want to use a cycling app for cycling, but Nike+ as my overall tracker.  Hence I would like a cycling app that exports to Nike+ - which Wahoo Fitness does, but I'm not convinced by its tracking.

Comment: OK, from what I've seen today, Wahoo will sync to both Nike+ and Strava, so you could have new activities fed to both.

Comment: @BlueChippy - if you want to keep years of records I wouldn't trust any online service, all will be discontinued at as soon as the economics stop being favorable.  Plus most online services are designed to make it easy to get data into, but difficult to get data out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old article, but I thought you'd like to know that you can also sync Garmin TO Nike+, but not the other way around. And it does accurately transfer your data. It does automatically title it a run, but when you go to the Nike website, it does recognize it as cycling.